# UnsatisfiedLinkError when enabling JProfiler on armhf

Tags: java, docker, raspberry-pi3, jprofiler

I am trying to start a JProfiler agent in a docker container running on a Raspberry PI 3. Here is the complete Dockerfile.

```
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3-openjdk

RUN ["cross-build-start"]
RUN curl -SL http://download-keycdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_11_0.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local && \
  echo 'sudo -u root /usr/local/jprofiler11.0/bin/jpenable -g -p 8849' > /jprofile.sh && \
  chmod +x /jprofile.sh
RUN [ "cross-build-end" ]

ENV JPAGENT_PATH="-agentpath:/usr/local/jprofiler11.0/bin/linux-armhf/libjprofilerti.so=nowait"
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
EXPOSE 8849

ADD build/libs/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar

ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

For profiling, run:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/bash -c "/jprofile.sh"
```

Here is the complete output:

```
Connecting to app.jar [1] ... ERROR: The agent could not be loaded: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.isLinuxThreads()Z
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.isLinuxThreads(Native Method)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<clinit>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:343)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.jprofiler.attach.proxy.a.e$b.invoke(ejt:110)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.attach(Unknown Source)
        at com.jprofiler.attach.a.main(ejt:119)
```

It seems like the native library loads fine when I call `System.loadLibrary("attach")` from `jshell`. Any ideas what could be causing this exception?

Comment: Attach mode is indeed currently not supported on linux-armhf. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com and I'll send you a build where we add the missing native library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved via `support@ej-technologies.com` - if you place the correct file in `lib/libattach.so`, you can add the following snippet to the Dockerfile to make it work.

Offical support for armhf is scheduled to release with `11.0.1`.

```
# ...
# Add ARMHF remote attach library (acquired via EJ Technologies support)
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307915/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-enabling-jprofiler-on-armhf
ADD lib/libattach.so /usr/local/jprofiler11.0/bin/linux-armhf/
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/jprofiler11.0/bin/linux-armhf/libattach.so

RUN [ "cross-build-end" ]
```

Special thanks to Ingo Kegel!